# Connect TOAD to Oracle using JDBC connection

Tags: toad

Is it possible to connect to an Oracle DB using a jdbc connection string like:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@myserver:1521:mydb
```

instead of using TNS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as the JDBC driver JAR is in the CLASSPATH.

Comment: Agreed. Toad will allow you to connect via a number of types of connections. Oracle Client or JDBC.